# Facebook Graph API: Get Events by Venue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to query all the events for a specific **venue**?
I noticed that there is no such entity Venue - it is a structure inside the event object.

Assuming there isn't, what do you think about the following solution?

1. Query all the events in the proximity of the Venue (I got the venue coordinates)
2. Filter all events that do not match the Venue ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are right. The only way forward being to filter all the events by venue.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now there is not a way via pure SQL. It'll get pretty ugly having to track all the events, and there are no assurances you got every event.  There may that one facebook user who invites his 30 best friends for a birthday party, though I presume that is not much a worry.